# I can't set a data value using rule on a custom entity

Tags: 7, entities, rules

I have created a custom entity "Project" with this fields: `id, name.`

I have created a rule and added an action "`create entity`" and selected "Project".

I have added another action "`Set a data value`" and selected "`name`" of the newly created entity project and I had this message : "`The selected data property doesn't support writing`."

Here is the entity property info

```
 /**
 * Implements hook_entity_property_info().
 */
function project_entity_property_info() {

  $info = array();

  $info['project']['properties']['id'] = array(
    'label' => t('Project ID'),
    'description' => t('The ID of the project.'),
    'type' => 'integer',
    'schema field' => 'id',
  );

  $info['project']['properties']['name'] = array(
    'label' => t('Project name'),
    'description' => t('Name of the project.'),
    'type' => 'text',
    'schema field' => 'name',
  );
  $info['project']['properties']['description'] = array(
    'label' => t('Project description'),
    'description' => t('Description of the project.'),
    'type' => 'text',
    'schema field' => 'description',
  );
  $info['project']['properties']['deadline'] = array(
    'label' => t('Deadline'),
    'description' => t('Project deadline.'),
    'type' => 'date',
    'schema field' => 'deadline',
  );

  return $info;
}
```

Comment: What is the field type of "name"?

Comment: name's type varchar

Comment: Can you edit your question to provide your implementation of `hook_entity_property_info()`? If you don't know what that means, that's the problem :)

Comment: You've added the wrong hook @sel_space, we need to see the hook I mentioned in the previous comment, not hook_entity_info

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the provided hook, You need to add the **setter callback**.

So it will be like:

```
function project_entity_property_info() {
  // .... rest of code removed for brevity.    

  $info['project']['properties']['name'] = array(
    'label' => t('Project name'),
    'description' => t('Name of the project.'),
    'type' => 'text',
    'schema field' => 'name',
    'setter callback' => 'entity_property_verbatim_set', // -> this is it!
  );
```

Now rules knows how to set the value on entity.

More information about the `hook_entity_property_info` can be found [here](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!entity!entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_property_info/7). If `name` requires a complex workflow to be set, you can write your own setter similar to `entity_property_verbatim_set` (for validating purposes, or ...).

If you are benefiting from the power of [Entity API](http://drupal.org/project/entity) you may declare it in your EntityMetadataController class. There is a default class called [EntityDefaultMetadataController](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!entity!entity.info.inc/class/EntityDefaultMetadataController/7) you can extend it and introduce it as your entity type's metadata controller.

Another option is to use [entityspice](http://drupal.org/project/entityspice) to declare your entity type which takes care of it all.